# Outlook 2016 stopped syncing IMAP folders. Sync only when INBOX folder is active

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, sync, imap, inbox

A few days ago I caught a glitch on MS Windows server - MS Outlook 2016 stopped correctly synchronizing mail via IMAP from a Linux server (Dovecot + Exim). The problem: i send a letter on my mailbox (from anywhere), then wait, and there's a bit of magic: if the cursor is on the Inbox folder mail arrives immediately. If any other folder is active, for example, Deleted Items or Sent Items the letter does not arrive no matter how long you wait for it. Timer also doesn't work ("Send / Receive" settings, where the standard 30 minutes can be changed). Then I click on the Inbox folder and all the letters arrive immediately.

What has been tried:

- Deleting Outlook Profile Deleting and re-creating accounts,
- Outlook safe mode,
- Scanpst,
- Firewalls off,
- Antiviruses off,
- Rollback to Outlook 2013,
- Reinstall Office or Fix Office installation,
- clean Windows user profile,
- changing root folder to INBOX, Inbox,
- unsubscribe and subscribe to IMAP folders,
- Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant.

None of the above helped.

At first I thought that the problem was with the mail server on Linux, but there were no updates and configuration did not change. Then, there may be a problem with Windows Server, where Outlook is installed, but I reproduced exactly the same bullshit on home Windows 10 + MS Office 2016 and even with other IMAP mail server like Gmail.

I asked my friends to test their Outlook behavior - the same thing. If the active folder is different from the Inbox, then the letters will not come.
Other programs, for example, Mozilla's Thunderbird, work like a charm: if you send a letter, it comes right away. Even mobile Outlook at Android works fine...

Deleting and recreating PST profile in Outlook 2013 help only till Outlook restart, then in fails again.

I even tried Outlook 2010 - it works perfectly! But it too old to use.

Where is the problem? I'm tired trying fixing this..

Upd.
Found interesting link, saying that: .. there are two synchronization options: using IMAP IDLE (also known as "Live Sync") and creating schedules for subscribed folders. You can use IMAP IDLE to maintain the connection to the IMAP server and apply changes that you make to the read, unread, or flagged status of messages on the server. But you can maintain the connection to only one folder at a time. You can also create schedules that synchronize your subscribed folders in Outlook with the IMAP mail server.

That means Outlook cannot sync different folders an once, but how did it work before? O_o

But this is about Mac version.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, your issue seems to be similar to this thread. Please refer to the reply of Jeff Yang MSFT, which mentioned defining the send / receive operations of our email accounts on our own via "send / receive groups": [outlook 2013 does not sync emails until you open "inbox"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/325789/outlook-2013-does-not-sync-emails-until-you-open-3.html#:%7E:text=define%20the%20send/receive%20operations%20of%20our%20email%20accounts%20on%20our%20own%20via%20%22Send/Receive%20groups%22). Hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks, but there are no any solution to my problem. And yes, it's seem the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that it's useful to modify the sync frequency time to 1 minute as mentioned in that theard. Maybe you can try the suggestion if possible.

Comment: I've already set sync time to 1 minute, but as described in my post and at the link you suggested if Inbox is not active folder new mail doesn't come.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Based on my test, this issue will not occur when configuring an IMAP account in a separate profile. Therefore, as a workaround, please try to configure your IMAP account in a single folder to check if you can receive the emails when other folder is active.

Comment: Tried that already, creating clean profile with only one account. Doesn't work.

Comment: Based on my test on outlook 2016, if an IMAP account is configured in a separate profile, each folder can be synchronized normally when I modify the sync frequency time to 1 minute. In order to prevent other problems caused by the version is not updated, please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version. And then, considering corruption in send/receive settings file may cause this issue, You can try to reset the SRS file to check if there're any differences.(To C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook>Rename the .srs file to Outlook.srs.old>restart Outlook)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: It sync normally only when Inbox folder is active and selected. When some other folder is active, like Sent or Trash there are no new mail till Inbox folder selected.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion above and if there are any differences after that?

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt seem to be resolved?  I have 6 email accounts on my 2016 Outlook, 2 POP and 4 IMAP.  One of the IMAP accounts behaves exactly as you describe, only updating the inbox when that inbox is opened.  It does 'sometimes' update when in a different folder and a full send/receive is done, but not always.

I have given up trying to work it out and assume it must be something to do with the server since the other 3 IMAP folders work fine. One of the others is Gmail, one is a Google hosted Mail, one is my own cpanel hosting and the one that's not working is Crazy Domains...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1148247)